# horizontal scrolling loop in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I'm after some help, I have a div that spans the width of a page, it has a horizontal scroll bar witch content that goes beyond the width of the DIV, I'd like to be able to scroll the div along so that the content will keep looping continuously.

This [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGbLB) seems to be similar to what I'm after, however I dont want it to be so jittery.

I hope i've explained what Im trying to do well enough, but tell me if its not clear! If anyone can help that would be great! There are lots of examples that let you scroll down the page vertically, but there seem to be none vertically.

this code that I found is exactly what im after, but just in a div that scrolls horizontally.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$(document).scroll(function(){
if(document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
$(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )$(document).scrollTop(0);
         });
     });
```

Comment: okay, but if i can manage to scroll down a page and back to top without being jittery, surely it is more to do with the code rather than a graphics card?

Comment: try to combine your code with jQuery animate interpolation, it will be a bit smoother at least...